# Android app disable/enable status or disabling app over updater script

Tags: android

I need to disable systemUI over updater-script.

1) I use 'pm disable' command to enable or disable app and I want to know what file changes when I do that to replace it with updater script.

2) If anyone knows how to do it the other way, please tell.

```
run_program("/system/bin/pm", "disable com.android.systemui");
```

does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Found that file in */data/system/users/0*  - **package-restrictions.xml**

 Just added the 3rd line here

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
    <package-restrictions>
    <pkg name="com.android.systemui" enabled="2" enabledCaller="shell:0" />
```